# How to say news in Alexa with Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm developing an Alexa Skill calling the Amazon Web Service lambda function made with Node.js.
The function gets an RSS with the news and I take the title of each news. I put them in one array (last_news) and I send it to Alexa with this function:

```
const GetLastNewsHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'LastNewsIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const last_news = await getLastNews();
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
        .speak("" + last_news)
        .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
        .getResponse();
  },
};
```

I would like that when the user says 'next' while Alexa is saying the news, it changes to a new news.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Create your own custom intent with the name of "next" and trained with
>   sample utterances like "continue", "change"

then check in lambda function

```
request.type === 'IntentRequest' && request.intent.name === 'next';
```

then call the `handler` function

Comment: You can use the built-in AMAZON.NextIntent too. To cycle through an array, you'll need to save `sessionAttributes` with the array and current count. And on each iteration, increase the count and serve the feed from the array.